# Php pass throught bootstrap

Tags: php, web, bootstrapping

Is it possible to have a single php file that gets called before the actual requested page is loaded, so like a bootstrap.

What I would like to do is be able to have a php script be called, setup globals, ini_sets, etc and than continue to a page like index.php, about.php, etc.

I've looked at this article already, but it almost seems to follow more of a mvc pattern, (minus the model...sorta)

http://www.serversidemagazine.com/php/bootstrap-php-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mod rewrite to rewrite example.com/about/ to index.php?p=about.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Index.php would then be your bootstrap file and after setting up globals and such you could run `include 'about.php'`;

Answer (score 0):

see the `auto_prepend_file` php setting. you can set it in the main php.ini, or in user level .ini files, and other config sources like .htaccess files.

Comment: I'm not sure I can have user leve ini files, as I can never get my include path to work, or atleast when i do phpinfo... is there a way to check if you can user level ini.

Comment: look for for the string user_ini in phpinfo() output, and then make a file by that name. as usual, check the docs for more info. http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: according to the docs, thats not going to work for me, as I'm currently stuck with 5.29 for php